# How best to retrieve a twitter timeline and media with API version 1.1?

Tags: javascript, php, api, twitter

Looking for a way to retrieve tweets (including photos/gifs/videos) to create a custom twitter feed.

Would like to layout each tweet as follows (and of course be able to style)

```
(image/video/gif)
(tweet time)
(tweet text)
```

I understand that I need to use twitter API Version 1.1 and authenticate with OAuth since the new update..

I'm such a newbie...What programming language would be best for this?

Would someone be able to kindly provide or help me create the code for this? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: We don't really suggest programming languages here, neither do we provide coding services.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm more asking for help on where to get started or what way would be best to approach this with retrieving information through the twiiter API